# Nuxt.js Cannot use Vuex in RouteMiddleware

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js, vuex, middleware

I'm currently creating a project using Nuxt.js and Firebase-admin.
I want to route with reference to Vuex user information in Route Middleware, but I can't access Vuex in Route Middleware.

`store/index.js` code is below.

```
export const state = () => ({
  user: {},
});

export const getters = {
  getUser: state => state.user,
};

export const mutations = {
  setUser(state, payload) {
    state.user = payload;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit, getters }, { req }) {
    if (process.server && process.static) return;
    if (!req.headers.cookie) return;

    if (req.headers.cookie) {
      const parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie);

      const accessTokenCookie = parsed.access_token;
      if (!accessTokenCookie) return;

      admin.auth().verifyIdToken(accessTokenCookie)
      .then(decodedToken => {
        const userInfo = {
          email: decodedToken.email,
          uid: decodedToken.uid
        };
  
        commit("setUser", userInfo); 
　　　　console.log('uid in nuxtServerInit is ' + getters.getUser.uid)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      });  
    } else {
      return 
    }
  },
};
```

`middleware/validateRoute.js` code is below.

```
export default function({ store, redirect, route }) {
  const currentPath = route.path;
　console.log("uid in middleware is " + store.getters.getUser.uid);

  if (
    !!store.getters.getUser.uid &&
    (currentPath === "/auth/signup" || currentPath === "/auth/login")
  ) {
    return redirect("/");
  }

  if (
    !store.getters.getUser.uid &&
    currentPath !== "/auth/signup" &&
    currentPath !== "/auth/login"
  ) {
    return redirect("/auth/login");
  }
};
```

When I look at the console, `store.getters.getUser` is undefined even though Vuex user has a value.

**console.log image is here.**
[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Not sure but can you verify if your store is instantiate when you access your middleware and that the value you see of the user is not populated later on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I searched for instantiation, but I'm not very sure. I'm sorry.
However, when I went through nuxt-link after logging in, I was able to confirm that the user information was acquired by Route Middleware.
Also, I haven't changed the user information later.
Sorry for my poor English.